# Understanding Beta distribution in prior belief distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian, beta-function

I was looking at the *Bernoulli Distribution* and its relation to the *Prior Belief Distribution*. The equation is written as
$$
\frac{x^{\alpha - 1}(1-x)^{\beta -1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)}.
$$

I've also studied the properties of the of the *Beta function* which is define as
$$
B(x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} \, \mathrm dt.
$$

The *Beta function* is basically the integral of the *Bernoulli Distribution* from what I can see.

I graphed the *Prior Belief Distribution* for a couple of variations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and noticed that dividing by the *Beta function* squashes the height of the distribution by some amount.

My question is what is the *Beta function* doing exactly. Is it squashing the distribution to within some range? If so, can someone show me a proof as to why this works so that I can internalize it better?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle by replacing them with inline LaTeX. (This is particular silly since the images you used were from an online LaTeX render).

Comment: @Brian thanks, sorry about that. I am used to using stackoverflow which does not allow using latex. old habit

Comment: In general, $\frac{f(x)}{\int_{t=-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,dt}$ normalizes $f(x)$ so that the area under the curve is $1$, which goes toward making it a probability distribution.  (And similarly for two, three, etc. variables, adjusting for the support of $f(x)$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main job of the $B(\alpha, \beta)$ function here is to normalise the distribution, i.e. ensure that it has integral $1$ when integrated over the whole range. Can you see why that is?

Comment: So in other words, if I were to graph $\frac{x^{\alpha - 1}(1-x)^{\beta -1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)}$, we always want to ensure that the area under the curve is equal to 1 between interval 1 and 0?

Comment: Yep that's exactly it